# Access query doesn't return correct values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a long query in Access. But it doesn't return correct values.
Because access has problem with null values. This is my query:

```
SELECT courses.coursename as coursename
   ,scores.coursecode as coursecode
   ,val(scores.score) as score 
FROM courses,scores
where scores.timeyear='96'
  and scores.dore='1'
  and scores.stdcode in
   (
     Select stdcode
     from classbandi
     where classid='12'
   )
  and scores.coursecode=courses.coursecode
  and scores.score is null
  and scores.coursecode <> '7991'
order by scores.coursecode
```

When I run this query, this part **(scores.score = '')** likes not in query.
What is problem and what I must to do to solve this problem?

this query must return all null values in db that stored in scores.score table.
but it can't return any value.
[access database download link](http://www.rahbordrayaneh.ir/Download/karnadb-1.mdb)

nobody can't solve this problem?!?!

Comment: We need to see the schema for `scores`. And tell us why you think something “likes not in query”. Are you getting an error message? We need to see that as well.

Comment: To compare to a NULL you must use `scores.score IS NULL`

Comment: If you filter by `scores.score = ''` (or `scores.score IS NULL`), how can you expect `val(scores.score) as score` to return a value? Also, you did not join the tables `courses` and `scores`.

Comment: i attach my db. please test it.

Comment: i want val(scores.score) return zero(0) for test dear friend and then i replace IS NULL criteria with <>. because when i use <> in query it returns all scores with null values and I don't want it returns null values.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an MS Access database (presumably).  If so, I would expect the query to look like this:

```
select c.coursename as coursename,
       s.coursecode as coursecode,
       val(s.score) as score 
from courses as c inner join
     scores as s
     on s.coursecode = c.coursecode
where s.timeyear = "96" and
      s.dore = "1" and
      s.stdcode in (select cb.stdcode from classbandi as cb where cb.classid = "12") and
      (s.score is null or s.score = "") and -- or whatever logic you want here
      s.coursecode <> "7991"
order by s.coursecode;
```

I'm not sure if this actually addresses your problem.  Without sample data and desired results *in the question* it is hard to figure out what the problem really is.

Comment: i attach my db. please check it.

Comment: @parham2501 . . . That is not how this site works.  You should include sample data and desired results as *text tables* in the question.  You can also use one of the various "fiddle" sites to provide sample data -- however, none of those support MS Access.

Comment: i test this query but it can't return any result. i have some blank score, but no result return.

Answer (score 0):

Handle isnull condition for all predicated in where clause

Comment: dear friend it is not different between is null and '' in query. you can test it. i attach database and my query is in.